# How to add Access Policy to Azure Logic App (Standard)

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, azure-logic-apps

I am trying to secure my HTTP triggers using AzureAD but I am running into an issue where the Authorization setting does not appear to exist in standard logic apps only consumption as shown here:[image]

Can anyone help me with how I would be able to do this with a standard logic app? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

> I am trying to secure my HTTP triggers using AzureAD but I am running into an issue where the Authorization setting does not appear to exist in standard logic apps only consumption as shown here:

Yes, In standard Logic Apps there is no section on Authorization as you can check below:

[image]

If you want to use Azure AD you can use **Access control (IAM)**

[image]

Now after clicking select the role you want to give to a particular user or group.
You can also give contributor role(Complete permissions i.e access).

[image]

Then click on Select members.

[image]

Then click on Save button  to add  a access policy using IAM.

You can also use [API Management](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/logic-apps/logic-apps-securing-a-logic-app?tabs=azure-portal#expose-your-logic-app-with-azure-api-management) for Restricting access or Full control on your Logic app.

You can also use Managed Identity in Logic apps .

Comment: Will this prevent anyone from being able to trigger the logic app? Only the role assignment set in Access Control?

Comment: No, the user/ group with access can trigger the logic app.